# Java RCP Plug-in sharing failed by 'unresolved requirement: osgi.ee'?

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I have developed an plugin, with is included in a feature and shared in a local Updatesite. Typical developer issue, on my local machine all works great. I can install the plugin from the update site and it works well. Now I tried it on an other PC and the plugin is not loaded.
I restart the eclipse with the -consoleLog parameter and get the error

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.myPlugin.ing.logging.Remote [177]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))"
```

The java version fits. Now comes  the problem from the osgi.ee. I don't have it included directly. The Target Platfom is a RCP application, based on Eclipse 4.15. My Dependencies are the following 'Required Plug-ins':

```
org.eclipse.ui
org.eclipse.core.runtime
```

The specs are:

- Java 11
- Eclipse 4.15

I tried to make the Dependency Analysis -> all ok. "Automated Managment of dependencies" also can't find missing dependencies.

Any hint what I have to include to remove the problem with the osgi.ee?

The target is on the other PC exact the same, the Java versions also. On the dev PC I can run the target also standalone and the plugin works, without this osgi.ee issue.

The goal is to install the plugin only, without installing some things out of the box.

The plugins in the target are:

```
com.ibm.icu_64.2.0.v20190507-1337.jar
com.sun.jna.platform_4.5.1.v20190425-1842.jar
com.sun.jna_4.5.1.v20190425-1842.jar
javax.annotation_1.2.0.v201602091430.jar
javax.inject_1.0.0.v20091030.jar
org.apache.batik.constants_1.11.0.v20190515-0436.jar
org.apache.batik.css_1.11.0.v20190515-0436.jar
org.apache.batik.i18n_1.11.0.v20190515-0436.jar
org.apache.batik.util_1.11.0.v20190515-0436.jar
org.apache.commons.codec_1.13.0.v20200108-0001.jar
org.apache.commons.io_2.6.0.v20190123-2029.jar
org.apache.commons.jxpath_1.3.0.v200911051830.jar
org.apache.commons.logging_1.2.0.v20180409-1502.jar
org.apache.felix.gogo.command_1.0.2.v20170914-1324.jar
org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_1.1.0.v20180713-1646.jar
org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_1.1.0.v20180713-1646.jar
org.apache.felix.scr_2.1.16.v20200110-1820.jar
org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient.win_4.5.10.v20200113-2105.jar
org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient_4.5.10.v20200114-1512.jar
org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore_4.4.12.v20200108-1212.jar
org.apache.xmlgraphics_2.3.0.v20190515-0436.jar
org.csstudio.swt.xygraph_2.1.0.201209121540.jar
org.eclipse.compare.core_3.6.800.v20191213-2246.jar
org.eclipse.compare_3.7.900.v20200129-0902.jar
org.eclipse.core.commands_3.9.700.v20191217-1850.jar
org.eclipse.core.contenttype_3.7.600.v20200124-1609.jar
org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans_1.6.100.v20191217-1850.jar
org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable_1.9.0.v20200205-2119.jar
org.eclipse.core.databinding.property_1.8.0.v20200124-0715.jar
org.eclipse.core.databinding_1.8.0.v20200205-2008.jar
org.eclipse.core.expressions_3.6.700.v20200212-1751.jar
org.eclipse.core.filebuffers_3.6.900.v20200117-0616.jar
org.eclipse.core.filesystem_1.7.700.v20200110-1734.jar
org.eclipse.core.jobs_3.10.700.v20200106-1020.jar
org.eclipse.core.resources_3.13.700.v20200209-1624.jar
org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.17.100.v20200203-0917.jar
org.eclipse.core.variables_3.4.800.v20200120-1101.jar
org.eclipse.draw2d_3.10.100.201606061308.jar
org.eclipse.e4.core.commands_0.12.900.v20200110-1732.jar
org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts_1.8.400.v20191217-1710.jar
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations_1.6.600.v20191216-2352.jar
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions.supplier_0.15.500.v20200106-1259.jar
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions_0.15.500.v20200106-1259.jar
org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.7.500.v20190916-2125.jar
org.eclipse.e4.core.services_2.2.200.v20200127-0814.jar
org.eclipse.e4.emf.xpath_0.2.600.v20191216-0805.jar
org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings_0.12.800.v20191216-0805.jar
org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.12.1000.v20200129-0903.jar
org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme_0.12.600.v20200124-0005.jar
org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt_0.13.900.v20200203-0840.jar
org.eclipse.e4.ui.dialogs_1.1.700.v20200201-1719.jar
org.eclipse.e4.ui.di_1.2.800.v20200128-0855.jar
org.eclipse.e4.ui.ide_3.15.0.v20200113-2039.jar
org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench_2.1.700.v20200113-1422.jar
org.eclipse.e4.ui.services_1.3.700.v20190930-1643.jar
org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets_1.2.700.v20191222-1048.jar
org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt_1.3.800.v20191212-1231.jar
org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt_0.14.1100.v20200217-1217.jar
org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt_0.14.900.v20200213-1442.jar
org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench3_0.15.400.v20191216-0805.jar
org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench_1.11.200.v20200205-1503.jar
org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer_5.1.0.v20200217-0016.jar
org.eclipse.ecf.identity_3.9.300.v20191020-1846.jar
org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient45.win32_1.0.100.v20200212-0036.
org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient45_1.0.200.v20200212-0036.jar
org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.ssl_1.0.101.v20191012-1926.jar
org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer_3.2.500.v20191017-1905.jar
org.eclipse.ecf.ssl_1.2.300.v20191012-1926.jar
org.eclipse.ecf_3.9.5.v20200217-1548.jar
org.eclipse.emf.common_2.18.0.v20191225-1014.jar
org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change_2.14.0.v20190528-0725.jar
org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi_2.16.0.v20190528-0725.jar
org.eclipse.emf.ecore_2.21.0.v20200127-1342.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.4.400.v20191212-0743.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.bidi_1.2.300.v20191213-1901.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.11.0.v20200206-0817.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.concurrent_1.1.500.v20200106-1437.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.4.0.v20190819-1430.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.5.300.v20191001-1333.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.frameworkadmin.equinox_1.1.300.v20200211-1503.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.frameworkadmin_2.1.400.v20191002-0702.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.1100.v20190907-0426
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.700.v20200207-2156.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository_1.3.400.v20191224-0854.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.console_1.1.300.v20191014-1219.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core_2.6.300.v20200211-1504.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director.app_1.1.500.v20200211-1504.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.directorywatcher_1.2.500.v20191211-1631.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director_2.4.600.v20200211-1504.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine_2.6.600.v20200110-2121.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.extensionlocation_1.3.400.v20191213-1911.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector_1.1.400.v20200221-1022.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.jarprocessor_1.1.600.v20200217-1130.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository_1.3.400.v20191211-1528.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata_2.4.700.v20191213-1911.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations_2.5.700.v20191211-1713.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.eclipse_1.3.500.v20200203-1449.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher_1.5.300.v20191016-0507.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins_1.3.300.v20191211-1631.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.tools_2.2.500.v20200110-2121.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository_2.4.700.v20200110-2121.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse_2.2.600.v20200114-1339.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives_1.3.500.v20200218-1022.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf_1.2.400.v20200123-2221.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.importexport_1.2.400.v20191016-0512.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler_1.4.600.v20200221-0754.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk_1.1.500.v20191016-0512.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui_2.5.800.v20200213-1530.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatechecker_1.2.300.v20200222-1600.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite_1.1.300.v20191016-0515.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_3.7.700.v20191213-1901.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.8.700.v20200121-1457.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.security.ui_1.2.600.v20191213-1901.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.security.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20190812-0919.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.security_1.3.500.v20200114-1637.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.manipulator_2.1.500.v20200211-1505.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.3.500.v20200211-1505.jar
org.eclipse.help_3.8.700.v20191212-1123.jar
org.eclipse.jface.databinding_1.11.0.v20200205-2119.jar
org.eclipse.jface.text_3.16.200.v20200218-0828.jar
org.eclipse.jface_3.19.0.v20200218-1607.jar
org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.1.700.v20200207-2156.jar
org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.8.0.v20190206-2147.jar
org.eclipse.osgi.util_3.5.300.v20190708-1141.jar
org.eclipse.osgi_3.15.200.v20200214-1600.jar
org.eclipse.rcp_4.15.0.v20200305-0155.jar
org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.114.0.v20200304-0601.jar
org.eclipse.swt_3.114.0.v20200304-0601.jar
org.eclipse.text_3.10.100.v20200217-1239.jar
org.eclipse.ui.console_3.9.100.v20200215-1209.jar
org.eclipse.ui.editors_3.13.100.v20200130-1507.jar
org.eclipse.ui.forms_3.9.0.v20200213-1442.jar
org.eclipse.ui.ide_3.17.0.v20200217-1511.jar
org.eclipse.ui.navigator_3.9.200.v20200213-1442.jar
org.eclipse.ui.views_3.10.200.v20200213-1442.jar
org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor_3.14.100.v20200212-1049.jar
org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.118.0.v20200222-0719.jar
org.eclipse.ui_3.116.0.v20200203-1308.jar
org.eclipse.update.configurator_3.4.500.v20200225-0827.jar
org.sat4j.core_2.3.5.v201308161310.jar
org.sat4j.pb_2.3.5.v201404071733.jar
org.tukaani.xz_1.8.0.v20180207-1613.jar
org.w3c.css.sac_1.3.1.v200903091627.jar
org.w3c.dom.events_3.0.0.draft20060413_v201105210656.jar
org.w3c.dom.smil_1.0.1.v200903091627.jar
org.w3c.dom.svg_1.1.0.v201011041433.jar
```

Comment: `osgi.ee` is not a plug-in, it is a "capability". This just means the OSGi Execution Environment capability. This is saying it can't find a Java 11.

Comment: Right!! I added also the Java 1.8 and it works. What a simple solution. Thanks

Comment: I can't mark gregs answer as the solution, I don't see any way to do it. I see only the flag. :-(

Answer (score 1):

The message

```
Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))
```

is talking about the `osgi.ee` "capability" (not a plug-in). This is the "execution environment" that is required. The filter is requiring at least Java 11.